# How to keep the user logged in after refreshing the page in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, session, mern

I am working on a project and I've created a login page. I want to authenticate the user and keep the user logged in until he logs out. How do I do that using React, Express and MongoDB?

Comment: There are several tutorials online if you search.

Comment: Is security a concern, or you just want to "make it work"? If you want to do it seriously, you have some reading to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper basic implementation here is the followings:

- backend authentication service that is checking credentials

  - this can be implemented in express and mongodb
- the authentication service stores the user login status in session and cookies
- on each render, the react app first ask express app to get user login status

  - if the user was logged in then show user dashboard
  - if the user wasn't logged in then show login page

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser's localstorage and save the userInfo there and when he logs out you can clear the storage. You can check this [set localstorage](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-localstorage-with-react-hooks-to-set-and-get-items/)

Or you can make it from the server side with session-express and redis [express sesson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)